# Workout App Open Goal vs Calories question

Tags: apple-watch

On the workout app, for all of my workouts except “Outdoor Hiking” the default setting under the little green figure says “Open Goal” in bright green.  Under the Outdoor Walk it shows “750 Calories” in red. When I start it, the countdown ring is in red. How do I reset this to Open Goal and countdown ring in green ?

Answer (score 2):

The workout should show an ellipsis (3 dots) on the top right that you can tap. From there select **open** goal.

See [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204523) for more information on workouts.

[image: workout watch face]

[image: choose goal]